# Retriving iOS device standard background images

Tags: ios, image, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to access one of the Apple's standard background images (wallpapers) from an app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No You cannot and you must be aware of the sandbox environment of the iPhone which does not allow to access any resources from any other application on iPhone except some such as contacts , email app , etc.Moreover there would be copyright issue if you use the same image.
You can google to get the image:)

Answer (score 5):

A few of the Apple patterns are available to use. Check out the [`UIColor`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html) "System Colors" documentation. Here's a few that you can use:

`groupTableViewBackgroundColor` (pinstripes)
`viewFlipsideBackgroundColor`
`scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor` (the new linen texture from Notifications etc)
`underPageBackgroundColor` (under the page curl in Maps)

Use it like this:

```
UIColor *myBackgroundColor = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];
```

[See the examples here.](http://www.iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/UIColor)

Comment: I already knew about these (except for "underPageBackgroundColor", cool!), but I was referring to background images you can find in the settings app

Comment: By "background images" do you mean the icons, or the wallpapers?

Comment: I'm afraid this answer is not quite relevant to the question anyway.